# Unable to launch jupyter notebook from a newly created environment in anaconda

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

*After creating a new environment, it is not recognizing jupyter notebook when i am trying to launch it from there. Able to launch it from base environment.*

---

Preparing transaction: done

Verifying transaction: done

Executing transaction: done

To activate this environment, use

```
$ conda activate ipl_score
```

To deactivate an active environment, use

```
$ conda deactivate
```

(base) E:>conda activate ipl_score

(ipl_score) E:>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(ipl_score) E:>

Answer (score 1):

You can install `jupyter notebook` with `conda` or `pip`

pip

```
$ pip install notebook
```

conda

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge notebook
```

Start `jupyter notebook` using the command below in cmd

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook has to be **individually installed in every environment** you create.

If you have Anaconda Navigator installed, open the navigator, select the `ipl_score` environment and install Jupyter Notebook.

You can also install jupyter notebook from the command line using `pip` or `conda` in the activated environment.

`pip install notebook`

`conda install -c conda-forge notebook`

You can follow the below article if you need more information

https://jupyter.org/install